# Connect to Rserv running on Ubuntu remote desktop

Tags: r, rserve

I want to test some capabilities of R in a server mode. I want to realise that with using Ubuntu on a virtual machine and the Rserve package.

So after I installed R and the corresponding package on that machine, I can run that by "R CMD Rserve" which respond with the message "Rserv started in daemon mode". Also in the process monitoring I can see that the process Rserve is running now. You can see that at the screenshot I attached.
But when I try to connect my local computer via RStudio and RSconnect with the remote instance it is not able to connect. Since the damoen process is already running I guess it's just an issue of one missing configuration. 
Can someone help me out here ?

[image]

I set up the config file including following text:

```
remote enable
auth disable
plaintext enable
```

Is my general approach like using Ubuntu as a remote desktop connection and connect via my local RStudio with that a way which can work ?

Edit: 4.4.2017

Thanks a lot for the answers so far. In the meanwhile I get more familiar with Rserve.
So in order to test the connection attempts in the non-daemon mode I edited the Rserve.conf-file in the /etc/ directory (I added: **daemon disable**).
I tried both ways, like R CMD Rserve (with default finding of the .conf file) as well as explicitly specifying the file in the /etc/ directory. 
Although the there are less messages after executing the command, the shown message states **"Rserv started in daemon mode"**.
So, is it anoyhow possible to start Rserv on Ubuntu in non-daemon mode ?

Comment: Look closely at the [Rserv documentation](http://rforge.net/Rserve/) -- as I recall you need to set up a config file to **explicitly enable** network access which is disabled by default (which is a common security setting).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Don't use screenshot, included text.  If you really think you must include images look at the StackOverflow help to learn the markdown syntax to include them so they distill.  Make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: The next step would be --- and I have done all that too -- to start Rserve in non-daemon mode so that you see the connection attempts.  You just need patient trial and error to set the parameters right.  Once set up, it will work reliably "forever".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers so far. In the meanwhile I get more familiar with Rserve.
So in order to test the connection attempts in the non-daemon mode I edited the Rserve.conf-file in the /etc/ directory (I added: daemon disable).
I tried both ways, like R CMD Rserve (with default finding of the .conf file) as well as explicitly specifying the file in the /etc/ directory. Although the there are less messages after executing the command, the shown message states "Rserv started in daemon mode".
So, is it anoyhow possible to start Rserv on Ubuntu in non-daemon mode ?

Comment: I think I have done that chiefly for the debugging reason. And I think I set that via the config file.

Comment: Hi, it's me again. Just another question. I now can connect to Rserve from within the network. This works fine. But when I try to connect via my public IP adress it doesn't work. Although I already disabled the firewalls, used port fowarding and set up the config file in /etc/Rserve.conf with "remote enable". If I check the port on an online open port checker it even states "Port 6311 is open on xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"..Don't know what else I can do..?!

Comment: Do I have to use credentials compulsory here ?

Comment: I suspect that's between you and the networking. The local connection demonstrates that Rserve is setup correctly.

Comment: Hi, you mean that since I am able to connect a computer within the network with Rserve the configuration in the Rserve.conf file is alright and I should focus on network issues, right ?